# DNS Zone Transfer to secondary - not authoritative

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-server-2003

I Current have a small windows 2008 AD Domain, as well as 2 completely different forests and subnets. Each with its own unique domain running windows 2003 domains.

All subnets are properly routed via VPN tunnels, and I can ping the IP of the various domain controllers and DNS Servers properly.

When adding the allows Zone Transfer server IPs on the primary zone of the 2003 DNS servers, it worked properly and transferred to the secondary zones of both the 2008 domain as well as the other 2003 domain.

The problem occurs when I try to add the allowed Zone Transfer server IPs on the 2008 dns server. It resolves the hostname correctly, but gives a warning saying "This Server IP is not Authoritative for the required zone"

I have tried some googling, but can not seem to find an acceptable answer.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You get this when trying to add the 2003 DNS servers' IPs to the 2008 DNS server's Allow Zone transfer? Are your DNS zones AD integrated? If you are stuck you can tell the 2003 DNS servers to use the 2008 servers as conditional forwarders for the 2008 AD zones.

Comment: Yes, all of the zones in the 2x 2003 server domains, and 1x 2008 server domain are ad integrated, as they are the AD zones. My end goal is to establish a domain trust between all three domains to each other. What is unusual is that 2x 2003 domains were able to transfer zones after modifying the allow zone transfer.

Comment: What is your motivation for doing this? I'm a little bit lost on understanding why you would want to do this.

Comment: They are 3 domains that originally started as separate businesses. Now that they are under the umbrella of a single business, I am trying to link them together. With dns replicating between the 3 domains we can easily access PCs and servers by their FQDN. With the Domain trust set up I should be able to set up NTFS permissions on resources under a single user without having to create multiple logins on each domain for a single user to access resources.

Comment: I am really confused at which step is not working. You are right in that you need DNS resolution across all of these for the trusts to work properly but what step exactly is failing? The warning is not a big deal if it still lets you pull the zone. Which DNS server(s) are you unable to create the secondary zones on and which zones are failing?

Comment: I can start to create the secondary DNS zones on the 2003 domains, so that they can pull the primary DNZ zone from my 2008 domain. Of course at this particular time the secondary zones state they failed to transfer from the master as they are not on the 2008 dns allows transfer list

Then when I go to the 2008 DNS to add the secondary dns zone servers IPs to the Allowed Zone Transfer To list, it tells me "The server with this IP is not authoritative for the required zone"

Comment: Does the transfer succeed if you check "Allow zone transfer to any server"?

Comment: Nope. unsurprisingly.

While the DNS servers have 2 NIC cards, I have told the DNS service to ONLY run from a single IP corresponding to each server. Furthermore, On the Allowed Zone Transfer To portion, i have listed only those IPs mentioned in previous step.